# Firebase Retrieving multiple keys

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

l have following data structure:

[image]

l am trying to get values from multiple keys  in firebase database using angularfire2 . The first key is for user uid and the sec key is unique id . While my try to test my code below  l have  empty page  .

my Code

```
data: AngularFireList<any>;
 ngOnInit() {

  this.data =  this.af.list("/orders")
    this.data.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        map(changes =>
          changes.map(c => ({ $key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
        )
      ).subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.data = data;
        console.log('data', this.data)

      })
}
```

HTML

```
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data | keyvalue">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>#{{item?.value?.data.newproduct[0]?.item?.itemId}}</td>
                  <td><span>{{item.value.status}}</span></td>
                  <td>
                    <div data-color="#00a65a" data-height="20" class="sparkbar">{{item.value.data.Tot}}</div>
                  </td>
                  <td><a (click)="details(item,a)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i
                        class="fa fa-edit mr-2"></i>اضغط هنا</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </ng-container>
```

Console log

[image]

So there is anyway to get values and multiple keys for each one please ?

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: Sure , i have main key is USER UID . under USER UID is unique id . Also under unique id  is data . l want to get data from those keys above

Comment: so do you want all orders data one by one for each UNIQE userid.. ? and where you failed at ? any error message?

Comment: yes , that what i want . i  want all orders data one by one for each UNIQE userid . l have no error , i have only empty page no data

Comment: and inside Each UNIQUE userid record , there is one key  also too. have you try to get back to traverse inside of that level too  or not?

Comment: that is the problem , l am stuck in that key inside Each UNIQUE user id record

Comment: i think you have got your all data as you had mention in what is in console.log image above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212544/discussion-between-ali-ghassan-and-gaurangdhorda).

Comment: Hello @Ali Ghassan. Its been long time passed away. Can you share any updates regarding you promised me to pay. I need it very badly. Your payment helps me a lot now a days since i m also jobless too. Please help one developer in need and brings developer community up by helping each other. Thank you.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda , l am on my promise . But , since that time when the business owner canceled the project, I could not get a new job or contract. I appreciate your status , but at the same time, my situation is also pitiful. Once I get a new contract or a new job, I will contact you and transfer the money to you . Thank you

Comment: Thank you once again, Your small help ease the situation to my surviving life, now a days.

Comment: this project is old , see when i posted . 22 days ago man . now l am working on another project for practices

Comment: Hello, Its been long time passed away too. Can you Please full fill your promised amount to pay? I am waiting for your commitment. Thank you.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda l am on my promised . l am waiting amount next 20 day . when i have it , will transfer to you . dont worry

Comment: Thank You so much!

Comment: Hello,, is there Any Updates regarding payment from your side ?

Comment: Hello..  I am still waiting for your commitment. Please fulfill your due payment. Thank you!

Comment: Its been long time passed away.. Now you must complete your promise and need to have payment to me.